# Search for a keyword and get its count occurrence

Tags: text-processing, grep

I want to find out the occurrence of a keyword group by filename inside a directory.

***Example:***
Keyword - TEST (means TEST1, TEST2, etc. can be valid results)
Files - a.txt, b.txt etc. (inside a directory .. /tmp).

Output will be as follows.

```
a.txt - 4
b.txt - 5
c.txt - 0
```

I tried with `grep -o "TEST" a.txt` and this gives only TEST and its occurrences; like if a file has 3 occurrences (like TEST1, TEST_XXX, TESTXYES) the output will be

```
TEST
TEST
TEST
```

**OR** if multiple files search is not possible then OUTPUT should provide all the similar string  starting TEST;
for example,

```
TEST
TEST_1
TEST_2
TEST4
```

I tried the following, too.

```
grep -c "TEST" a.txt
```

but this gives only the count;
it does not give what was the entire text starting with TEST.

Comment: For keyword `TEST` does it count if it's found in `RETESTS`? What about in `Testament`?

Comment: I modified your question, tried making it readable, but you should really edit the question by yourself because it is still hard to understand what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you for showing us what you’ve tried.   But it doesn’t help much if we don’t understand what result you want.   Your title says “get its count”, and, in the first few lines, you say you want output like `a.txt - 4` / `b.txt - 5` / `c.txt - 0`.   But then when you tried `grep -c` (which should be the right answer), you complain that it gives only the count.   What result do you want?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

The `grep -c` prints number of matching *lines*, so you won't get right result in combination with `-o` option. I would pipe the output of `grep -o` to `uniq -c`:

```
$ echo 'test1 test2 test3' >/tmp/file1
$ echo 'test1 test2 test3 test4' >/tmp/file2
$ grep -o test /tmp/file* | uniq -c
  3 /tmp/file1:test
  4 /tmp/file2:test
```

You can pipe it further to modify the output with some text-processing tools.

Comment: It seems like the user wants to see the full names `TEST_1`, `TEST_2`, etc. so they may not want the `-o` option for grep at all.